# perl parsing grammar with regex with_actions class not called for match

Tags: perl

In the following code I'm using a class for the actions of the grammar. There's a flaw in the grammar where I don't match at the beginning of the line. I know how to fix that, but it's showing a behavior I don't understand. When it matches starting at the second character the action in the class isn't called.

here's the output, notice you see 'ANSWER called' for the first input but not for the second:

```
      info | Processing the main regex before any rule definitions
       |    |
       |    |...Treating <debug: run> as:
       |    |       \ Change run-time debugging mode to 'run'
       |    |
       |    |...Treating <Answer> as:
       |    |      |  match the subrule <Answer> 
       |    |       \ saving the match in $MATCH{'Answer'}
       |    |
       |     \___End of main regex
       | 
       | Defining a rule: <Answer>
       |    |...Returns: a hash
       |    |
       |    |...Treating <[Operand=Literal]> as:
       |    |      |  match the subrule <Literal> 
       |    |       \ appending the match to $MATCH{'Operand'}
       |    |
       |     \___End of rule definition
       | 
       | Defining a token: <Literal>
       |    |...Returns: a hash
       |    |
       |    |...Treating '?:' as:
       |    |       \ normal Perl regex syntax
       |    |
       |    |...Treating <MATCH=( [+-]? \d++ (?: \. \d++ )?+ )> as:
       |    |      |  match the pattern ( [+-]? \d++ (?: \. \d++ )?+ ) 
       |    |       \ saving the matched substring in $MATCH{'='}
       |    |
       |     \___End of rule definition
       | 

4 <<<==== here's my first input

=====> Trying <grammar> from position 0
4\n    |...Trying <Answer>
       |   |...Trying <[Operand=Literal]>
       |   |   |...Trying <MATCH=( [+-]? \d++ (?: \. \d++ )?+ )>
\n     |   |   |    \_____<MATCH=( [+-]? \d++ (?: \. \d++ )?+ )> matched '4'
       |   |    \_____<[Operand=Literal]> matched '4'

ANSWER called <<<=== the match and action is called

       |    \_____<Answer> matched '4'
--> 4
.4
=====> Trying <grammar> from position 0
.4\n   |...Trying <Answer>
       |   |...Trying <[Operand=Literal]>
       |   |   |...Trying <MATCH=( [+-]? \d++ (?: \. \d++ )?+ )>
       |   |   |    \FAIL <MATCH=( [+-]? \d++ (?: \. \d++ )?+ )>
       |   |    \FAIL <[Operand=Literal]>
       |    \FAIL <Answer>
        \FAIL <grammar>
=====> Trying <grammar> from position 1
4\n    |...Trying <Answer>
       |   |...Trying <[Operand=Literal]>
       |   |   |...Trying <MATCH=( [+-]? \d++ (?: \. \d++ )?+ )>
\n     |   |   |    \_____<MATCH=( [+-]? \d++ (?: \. \d++ )?+ )> matched '4'
       |   |    \_____<[Operand=Literal]> matched '4'

WHY no call to ANSWER here?

       |    \_____<Answer> matched '4'
--> HASH(0x634ee78)
```

and here's the code:

```
#!/grid/common/bin/perl -w 

use strict;

use v5.10;
use warnings;

use lib "/vobs/uth/perl";

my $calculator = do{
    use Regexp::Grammars;
    qr{
 <debug: run>
    <Answer>

        <rule: Answer>
        <[Operand=Literal]>

        <token: Literal>
        (?:
            <MATCH=( [+-]? \d++ (?: \. \d++ )?+ )>
        )
    }xms
};


while (my $input = <>) {

    if ($input =~ $calculator->with_actions('Calculator_Actions') ) {
        say '--> ', $/{Answer};
    }
    else {
    say {*STDERR} $_ for  @!;
    }
}

package Calculator_Actions;

use List::Util qw< reduce >;

sub Answer {
    my ($self, $MATCH_ref) = @_;

    say "ANSWER called";

    my $value = shift @{$MATCH_ref->{Operand}};

    return $value;
}
```

Comment: I had a quick look at this, and for now I suspect a bug in the library. The internal variable for the action class is not set on your 2. example.

Comment: any thoughts on how to proceed? guess I can narrow it down a little and submit it to the Regexp::Grammars folks.

Comment: If I may ask one other question : what does the $/{Answer} do?  can't quite figure where Answer comes from.

Comment: If you read the manpage it says: ` %/ # Result-hash for successful grammar match`. So it is a hash set by the library. I have looked at the action, and I don't understand how it is unset.

Comment: just figured that out again. I'm new to the parser I keep forgetting it returns things in %/.  thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've submitted a bug for this issue.

https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=111051

Comment: the bug was accepted by the regexp grammar folks and has been fixed in the release 1.45

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a bug in the library. If I add this to `clear_rule_handler`:

```
-sub clear_rule_handler { undef $RULE_HANDLER; }
+sub clear_rule_handler {
+    warn 'Clearing $RULE_HANDLER';
+    undef $RULE_HANDLER;
+}
```

I get this answer:

```
=====> Trying <grammar> from position 0
4\n    |...Trying <Answer>
       |   |...Trying <[Operand=Literal]>
       |   |   |...Trying <MATCH=( [+-]? \d++ (?: \. \d++ )?+ )>
\n     |   |   |    \_____<MATCH=( [+-]? \d++ (?: \. \d++ )?+ )> matched '4'
       |   |    \_____<[Operand=Literal]> matched '4'
ANSWER called
       |    \_____<Answer> matched '4'
Clearing $RULE_HANDLER at /Users/bolav/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.20.1/lib/site_perl/5.20.1/Regexp/Grammars.pm line 88, <> line 1.
--> 4
.4
=====> Trying <grammar> from position 0
.4\n   |...Trying <Answer>
       |   |...Trying <[Operand=Literal]>
       |   |   |...Trying <MATCH=( [+-]? \d++ (?: \. \d++ )?+ )>
Clearing $RULE_HANDLER at /Users/bolav/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.20.1/lib/site_perl/5.20.1/Regexp/Grammars.pm line 88, <> line 2.
       |   |   |    \FAIL <MATCH=( [+-]? \d++ (?: \. \d++ )?+ )>
       |   |    \FAIL <[Operand=Literal]>
       |    \FAIL <Answer>
        \FAIL <grammar>
=====> Trying <grammar> from position 1
4\n    |...Trying <Answer>
       |   |...Trying <[Operand=Literal]>
       |   |   |...Trying <MATCH=( [+-]? \d++ (?: \. \d++ )?+ )>
\n     |   |   |    \_____<MATCH=( [+-]? \d++ (?: \. \d++ )?+ )> matched '4'
       |   |    \_____<[Operand=Literal]> matched '4'
       |    \_____<Answer> matched '4'
Clearing $RULE_HANDLER at /Users/bolav/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.20.1/lib/site_perl/5.20.1/Regexp/Grammars.pm line 88, <> line 2.
--> HASH(0x7f9212003390)
```

So it looks like the rule_handler is cleared in the first position, and should be reset when trying again. If i do this with a quick hack:

```
 my $RULE_HANDLER_OLD;
 # Prepare for debugging...
 sub _init_try_stack {
     our (@try_stack, $last_try_pos, $last_context_str);

     # Start with a representation of the entire grammar match...
     @try_stack = ({
         subrule => '<grammar>',
         height  => 0,
         errmsg  => ' \\FAIL <grammar>',
     });

     # Initialize tracking of location and context...
     $last_try_pos     = -1;
     $last_context_str = q{};

     # Report...
+    if ($RULE_HANDLER) {
+        $RULE_HANDLER_OLD = $RULE_HANDLER;
+    }
+    else {
+        $RULE_HANDLER = $RULE_HANDLER_OLD;
+    }
+
     say {*Regexp::Grammars::LOGFILE} _debug_context('=>')
                 . 'Trying <grammar> from position ' . pos();
 }
```

The output is as you expect it, I think:

```
4
=====> Trying <grammar> from position 0
4\n    |...Trying <Answer>
       |   |...Trying <[Operand=Literal]>
       |   |   |...Trying <MATCH=( [+-]? \d++ (?: \. \d++ )?+ )>
\n     |   |   |    \_____<MATCH=( [+-]? \d++ (?: \. \d++ )?+ )> matched '4'
       |   |    \_____<[Operand=Literal]> matched '4'
ANSWER called
       |    \_____<Answer> matched '4'
Clearing $RULE_HANDLER at /Users/bolav/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.20.1/lib/site_perl/5.20.1/Regexp/Grammars.pm line 88, <> line 1.
--> 4
.4
=====> Trying <grammar> from position 0
.4\n   |...Trying <Answer>
       |   |...Trying <[Operand=Literal]>
       |   |   |...Trying <MATCH=( [+-]? \d++ (?: \. \d++ )?+ )>
Clearing $RULE_HANDLER at /Users/bolav/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.20.1/lib/site_perl/5.20.1/Regexp/Grammars.pm line 88, <> line 2.
       |   |   |    \FAIL <MATCH=( [+-]? \d++ (?: \. \d++ )?+ )>
       |   |    \FAIL <[Operand=Literal]>
       |    \FAIL <Answer>
        \FAIL <grammar>
=====> Trying <grammar> from position 1
4\n    |...Trying <Answer>
       |   |...Trying <[Operand=Literal]>
       |   |   |...Trying <MATCH=( [+-]? \d++ (?: \. \d++ )?+ )>
\n     |   |   |    \_____<MATCH=( [+-]? \d++ (?: \. \d++ )?+ )> matched '4'
       |   |    \_____<[Operand=Literal]> matched '4'
ANSWER called
       |    \_____<Answer> matched '4'
Clearing $RULE_HANDLER at /Users/bolav/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.20.1/lib/site_perl/5.20.1/Regexp/Grammars.pm line 88, <> line 2.
--> 4
```

I don't have overview of the sideeffects of my hack.

Comment: thanks for looking I've submitted a bug : https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=111051